# What does 春德东更 mean and in what language?

Tags: meaning, cantonese, simplified-characters

What does that phrase 春德东更 mean? I found the writing on a t-shirt (which you can see below). When I look up the phrase on Google and Google Translate, the results doesn't come up with any satisfying one.

And, is that in Chinese or Cantonese?

[image]

Comment: Good thing it wasn't a tattoo...

Comment: Since Cantonese is Chinese as well, you could ask "is it Cantonese, or some other dialect?"

Answer (score 3):

I'm Chinese, this phrase does not mean anything to me.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a Chinese idiom or other idiomatic expression, and doesn't mean anything.

春 spring

德 morality; Germany

东 east

更 change; more

Comment: spring time in the GDR.

Comment: well, people don't say it like that. You can say it like "东德的春天".

Comment: Just a joke dude